# Import mdb data into another mdb

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have two mdb files with equal structure (ca. 30 tables) but different data. I want to put the data together. Is there a user wizard to achive it in MS Access or do I have to do it manualy using INSERT for each table?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach (not import) tables from database A into database B. Then, for each table you can build a query to append data from A.tableX to B.tableX